# JSON response not captured by success function

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm making this simple ajax call to controller which returns a json object. 
Here's the code

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
$(function () {
    var submitButton = $("#submitButton");
    var infoForm = $("#infoForm");    
    submitButton.click(function() {
        submitInfo(infoForm)
    });
});
function submitInfo(formContainer) {      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Account")",
        data: formContainer.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        //some code
        return Json("ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here's the Html

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <fieldset id="infoForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.oldPassword)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.oldPassword, new { @class = "form-control", required = "" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.oldPassword)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newPassword)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.newPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.newPassword)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.confirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
                </div>

                <div class="text-danger">
                    @if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
                    {
                        @TempData["ErrorMessage"]
                    }
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Save</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It's a partial view I'm calling to show a pop up form.

But clicking on submit button returns a new view with only "ok"(with quotation marks) written on it. I get the same result even after I remove alert(). Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Your json response do not contain a property name `Message`. Just use `alert(data);` (or you could change the controller code to `return Json(new { Message = "ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` instead)

Comment: What is `console.log(data);`

Comment: You are anyways not using form submit action. Then change the type of your button to `type="button"`

Comment: If the element with `id="submitButton"` is a submit button or input, then you must cancel the default action (add `return false;` as the last line of the script - after `submitInfo(infoForm)`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i wrote it by mistake. Edited.

Comment: @ShaunakD i didn't give button any type. If I set it to button, it doesn't execute the onclick function at all

Comment: @Resham, Show the html for the element with `id="submitButton"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke done it, same result

Comment: @Resham, If your navigating to a new view, it means that you submitting your form (as well as making the ajax call)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's correct. Only that i don't want to navigate to a new form..

Comment: @Resham, I know. You need to show the html.

Comment: @Rayon Here it is.. (I really don't know what it means. I'm kinda new to it.)
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:64649/Account/ChangePassword".
browserLink:37 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
browserLink:37 Setting 'XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials' for synchronous requests is deprecated.
Navigated to http://localhost:64649/Account/ChangePassword

Comment: @Resham, You also need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've removed that and edited the question.

Comment: @Resham, first change the html to `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Save</button>`. Then if that's not working, are your loading that html dynamically (i.e. using ajax after the initial page has been loaded)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've tried that, it doesn't even lead to the controller. I'm using Html.Partial to load the html inside a div tag.

Comment: Which means that your not even executing the ajax :). Best guess is that you are in fact loading the partial dynamically. Instead of `submitButton.click(function() {` use `$(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function() {`

Comment: Oh no I meant I'm loading the original form using Html.Partial. The click function is working. Code in controller is executed.

Comment: @Resham. Now you have lost me. Are you saying that using `.on()` worked, or that it was working before?

Comment: @StephenMuecke $(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function() returns same result. I think the issue has something to do with form being popup, maybe.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It worked enough to get the controller executed. It doesn't handle the json response correctly.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being a popup. Put a breakpoint in the `submitInfo()` function. Is it being hit?

Comment: I can't put a breakpoint there. But I know it's being hit because i get correct values in controller's parameter.

Comment: What do you mean you cant put a breakpoint? Open you browser tools and find the script and add it. Or just add `console.log('got here');` and check the output. And it does not necessarily mean that its being executed. If you navigating to a new page, then you are making a normal submit (not ajax)

Comment: Also your ajax would not work correctly anyway - its needs to be `data: $(formContainer).serialize(),` although its unclear why you have a separate function for this anyway.

Comment: You were right. The function isn't being hit. Sorry I've been trying it since morning and now I'm kinda out of my mind.

Comment: @Resham, OK, Step 1 - change the script to `$("#submitButton").click(function() { alert('xxx'); });` If that does nothing use `$(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function() { alert('xxx'); });`. If that does nothing, then check your code again. Most likely you have a typo somewhere such as `SubmitButton` instead of `submitButton` or viceversa.

Comment: ok both of them didn't worked. Than I removed script type and made a javascript function instead of jquery which magically worked. Maybe I am missing some libraries for jquery or something. Thanks  for your help @StephenMuecke

Comment: Did you even check your console for errors. You need to include `jquery-{version}.js` in your view or layout.

Comment: I did but didn't get them. It was like my first experience with jquery and second with ajax. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: @Resham, You should delete the question. It of no use to anyone else.

Comment: stack overflow doesn't let you delete a question having answers.

Answer (score 0):

your controller should be,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
{
    //some code
    return Json(new { Message="OK"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: ok @Resham just put debugger in your success function, and see what data comes in data? is there any data.Message available or not..

Comment: what's not available, data or data.message?

Comment: @Bharat, You need to read the comments in the question - OP just made a typo an this has nothing to do with the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add async: false, to the ajax call or keep the entire Ajax call code block inside the click function.